# Galeria de imagens dentro do Accordion (Jquery)

Tags: jquery, html5, jquery-ui

Como faço para criar uma galeria de imagens dentro de um accordion, quero que ao clicar no acorddion a galeria ou slider vá passando as imagens automaticamente.

Ja tenho o accordion, porém não consigo encaixar nenhuma galeria de imagens responsiva nele.

[image: Slider/Galeria Accordion]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido o problema utilizando a biblioteca Jssor.Caroussel, que é uma galeria de imagens que se adapta a qualquer tamanho de tela e pode ser utilizada dentro de um accordion.